# What is the use of order by in sql injection

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL injection and I can't quite seem to understand the order by statement. 
The definition here in wwwschools is that this sorts the given table in ascending or descending. What happens when I use  a integer?

For example. 
Order by 1

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby
When I use order by 1 in this example, I get Customer ID arranged from 1to 91. 
When I use order by 2 in this example, I get customer ID arranged in a zig zag manner. 
What is the reason for this behaviour? And how is order by used in sql injection to obtain the number of columns?

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: Expanding on @JohnConde's comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I found the same definition "Used to arrange in ascending and descending order " in the other websites as well. :)

Comment: Ummm, you're not learning SQL *injection,* I hope. That's a technique criminals use to break into poorly coded web sites and steal private data. You're learning to use Structured Query Language to retrieve data from relational data management systems.

Comment: Knowledge is power. :) 
Order by statement is used for obtaining vulnerable columns in SQLi.
I just wanted to know how it works.

Comment: @OllieJones techniques _per se_ are agnostic to its uses, so learning them is not harmful. I learned SQL injection some time ago and it helped me to identify vulnerable code before an attacker could do us any harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `order by 1` means sort by values of the first column from the result set.
The `order by 2` means sort by values of the second column from the result set.

The order by clause in SQL has no direct relation to SQL injection AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

It may be useful as part of a blind SQL injection attack. You keep increasing the number  (which indicates which column in the `SELECT` clause should be used to determine the sort order) until the server suddenly reports an error. You now know the number of columns in the `SELECT` clause of the query (it's one less than the number you just tried)

Answer (score 0):

You asked two questions

Answer 1: `Order By` is used to order the result to the given SQL Query according to the Column Number given in SQL query.
For Example: `Order by 1` means order the result based on the first column in ascending order by default.

Answer 2: We use Order By for SQL Injection to check whether a given website is prone to SQL injection or not.
For Example
If I write `order by 1` in my SQL injection payload then it will give me some result
On the other hand if I write `order by 100000` then it most probably will give an error because it is very unlikely that my Table has these many columns. So `Order by` is used to check whether a website is vulnerable to SQL Injection or not. And the error confirms that the database was trying to understand my SQL Query but couldn't do it.
It's second use is to find the number of columns in our Table which we are exploiting. If you want more information on this then feel free to reply me in the comments